# Is there an up to date list of all common content types returned from web servers?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-type

For intance, text/html, audio/mpeg, etc? Can I safely assume that anything that is text based will actually have text/??? as its content type in the header when the server returns the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't assume that. There's types like 'application/xml' (which is exactly the same thing as 'text/xml', so I have no idea why they came up with that one).

Comment: Ok, is there a list of all these possibilities? Or maybe at least a list of all the common types that are most definitely not text based?

Comment: *application/xml* and *text/xml* is *not* the same. They behave differently when there is no `charset` parameter. Because the default charset value for *text/xml* is `us-ascii` while *application/xml* does not specify any default.

Answer (score 4):

The IANA acts as a central registry for official types. They provide a [directory](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) of content types and subtypes that is work a look.

When serving static content, the Apache web server uses a file called `mime.types` to map a file's extension to an appropriate content type. This can be taken from a fresh download of httpd itself, or from the Apache project's [SVN server](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types).